# Does my Gigabyte GA-EX58-UD4P motherboard support a SATA 3 SSD drive?

Tags: ssd

Can [this motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2986#sp), a Gigabyte GA-EX58-UD4P, support a SATA3 solid state drive?

> South Bridge:
>
> - 6 x SATA 3Gb/s connectors (SATA2_0, SATA2_1, SATA2_2, SATA2_3, SATA2_4, SATA2_5) supporting up to 6 SATA 3Gb/s devices
> - Support for SATA RAID 0, RAID 1, RAID 5, and RAID 10
>
> GIGABYTE SATA2 chip:
>
> - 1 x IDE connector supporting ATA-133/100/66/33 and up to 2 IDE devices
> - 2x SATA 3Gb/s connectors (GSATA2_0, GSATA2_1) supporting up to 2 SATA 3Gb/s devices Support for SATA RAID 0, RAID 1 and JBOD

I only see SATA 2.

Comment: But I see dead people. . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That mainboard only has SATA 2 controllers, but you can you a SATA3 drive on a SATA2 interface.  You just won't get the 6Gb/s. :)

Comment: yeah it seems to be only 3/gbs, hmm that's no fun!